# Share only text in facebook

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I am sharing predefine text in facebook. and i need to share only text not image or url. But getting this error.

[image]

```
let content = FBSDKShareLinkContent()

content.quote = "test"

let shareDialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
shareDialog.fromViewController = self
shareDialog.shareContent = content
shareDialog.delegate = self

if !shareDialog.canShow() {
    print("cannot show native share dialog")
}

shareDialog.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

It's limitation of Facebook SDK due to Platform Policy. You can get more information here ([Sharing on iOS - Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios)), but in a few words - you cannot share predefined text via Facebook Share Widget:

> Use of the iOS share sheet is subject to Facebook Platform Policy, including section 2.3 which states that apps may not pre-fill in the context of the share sheet. This means apps may not pre-fill the share sheet's initialText field with content that wasn't entered by the user of the app.

Comment: pre fill text is working but if i set with url or image.

Comment: It works if you try to share just a plain text, but it doesn't if you're sharing additional content such as URL, image, video, etc.

Comment: it does not matter if it is working somehow, prefilling is not allowed.