# How to share plain text with link using facebook sdk 4.0.1

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-share

I am trying to share plain text with link. But the problem is I could post only link, the plain text is not being shared on the ShareDialog. Here is how I am doing,

```
 private static ShareDialog shareDialog;

 private static void initFacebook(final Context context){
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(context.getApplicationContext());

    CallbackManager callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    shareDialog = new ShareDialog((Activity) context);

    shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
           // Toast.makeText(context, "Facebook succcess "+result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Toast.makeText(context, error.getMessage()+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

To show shareDialog

```
if(ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
                ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                        .setContentTitle("Download App Now")
                        .setContentDescription("Read or Share Viral messages")
                        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(str.SHORTEN_LINK))
                        .build();


                shareDialog.show(content);
            }
```

I wanted to include caption. I searched online but could not find anything.

[image: I want some text here]

I want to supply some text in the circled area. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The message part of any share or post has to be typed in by the user, your app is not allowed to specify it for them.

Comment: According to Facebook Platform Policy that is not allowed. I recommend that you read it

Comment: already answered https://stackoverflow.com/a/40780515/140220

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share only text in facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40780257/share-only-text-in-facebook)